# Vaadin-Grid: Select all check box does not work in the UI

Tags: select, checkbox, vaadin, vaadin-grid

**Problem:**

I have a grid with lazy loading and therefore my data is not in memory.

To show the check box to select/deselct all i used [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55262464/is-there-a-select-all-checkbok-in-vaadin-13-grid-that-works-even-with-filter/55276094#55276094).
My code looks like this:

```
Grid<CustomClass> grid;
...
// set selection mode
grid.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTI);
// make select all check box visible
GridSelectionModel<CustomClass> selectionModel = grid.getSelectionModel();
((GridMultiSelectionModel<CustomClass>) selectionModel)
    .setSelectAllCheckboxVisibility(SelectAllCheckboxVisibility.VISIBLE);
```

The Problem is, that the check box does not work in the UI as you can see:

[image]

If i log the selected items with the following code the check box works as expected

```
grid.addSelectionListener(l -> {
    log.info("selected: " + l.getAllSelectedItems().size());
});
```

**Question:**

*What can i do that the check box also works in the UI?*

Comment: What should selectAll mean in your case? Only the visible rows or all rows in the database?

Comment: All the visible rows. The size in the log is also all the visble rows.

Comment: You could store the fetched records and the pass them to grid.asMultiSelect().select();

Comment: What do you exaclty mean? i trie using `grid.asMultiSelect().select();` but it does not help.

Comment: I mean you have to pass all loaded objects to the method select

Answer (score 1):

The Solution i found that the checkoxes are updated in the UI is to add  `dataPovider.refreshAll()` in the listener.

**Code of the Solution:**

```
grid.addSelectionListener(l -> {
    ...
     dataPovider.refreshAll();
    ...
});
```